# PCRE seems to be removing particular characters

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I have a piece of text (part French part English) that has the European style Canadian Dollar symbols (`$C`) in it multiple times.  When I attempt to use a regex using either traditional or unicode characters, the symbols have been removed from the text and cannot be matched with. I used a lazy regex so that if it doesn't find the expected symbols it still works.

Additionally the text is in an xml utf-8 doc and being displayed from a web interface(made in house).

Comment: Why not show the code you tried, and some sample text?

Comment: sure text: Total ticket cost: 256,00 $C Taxes & Fees: 221,42 $C Airfare total: 477,42 $C Ottawa (Macdonald-Cartier Intl.) to Toronto (YYZ) 8 mars 2011 1:30 PM - 2:32 PM

Comment: regex: <?php                                         $cost = REGEX('$MONETARY$');    $pattern = '/ total: ((\D|\P{N})+?\s?)?(?:'.$cost.')\s?([$C])?/'; $match = GetMatch($pattern, $input,0,1); if(isEmpty($match)){ $match = GetMatch($pattern, $input,0, 0); }   return $match;?>

Comment: minor change: $pattern = '/ total: ((\D|\P{N})+?\s?)?(?:'.$cost.')\s?((\D|\P{N})+?\s?)?/';

Answer (score 0):

In perl, regex's and code are displayed in ascii, but if you want to embed unicode in your text, first you have to have an editor that does unicode, second you have to tell Perl your source code contains unicode (with a `use utf8'` pragma).

If you don't want to do that you can embed (in Perl) code points in strings (regex's) with a construct like this  $regex = /this is some text, this: is \x{1209} a codepoint unicode character/;

It matches the character IF the data source is decoded Unicode (internalized) and contains that character.

**Edit** - I don't think there is a unicode for canadian dollar, rather '$C', like someone said you have to escape the $ if the regex is interpolated.
If you keep the $C, the character class [$C] matches $ or C, not the combination. Maybe (?:\$|\$C) would be a better anchor.

Comment: I will eventually have to decode multiple symbols so using a specific character code is not valid here.

Comment: I believe that utf-8 may not have been enabled. Does anyone know how to check pcre and if not enabled easily enable it(without rebuilding)?

Comment: I changed the end of the pattern to (\$)? alone and it still can't find it so I am pretty sure it is unicode.

Comment: @Chris, if your string is single quoted, '\$' will try to match a literal \ then $, in that case '$' is what you want. Try a stand alone '/(.*?)$/' or '/$/' just for a match. Or you could try "/\$/" or even "/\x{0024}/".

Comment: Thanks can't use quotes with issues going into database. it basically comes down to the fact that those two characters are treated as " ".

Answer (score 0):

Escape the $ inside the RegExp, the dollar-sign has a special meaning in RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a bug in code just before i called eval().  Something in the french unicode was screwing with the code passed to eval, so by not combining the text and regex it worked fine.